# How to make more compact this F# code

Tags: f#, pipe, composition

I want to go from:

```
let a = fun x ->
        x
        |> f
        |> g
```

to something like this:

```
let a = |> f
        |> g
```

I tried:

```
let a = (<|)  f 
              |> g
```

and similars

Comment: Of course this is not real code and I'm not looking for a code review but for some pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let a = fun x -> x |> f |> g
```

is equivalent to

```
let a x = x |> f |> g
```

It looks like you want to compose two functions `f` and `g` to create a new function `a`. You can use the `>>` operator to compose functions. You could write:

```
let a = f >> g
```

If `f` and `g` are generic functions then it will fail to compile due to F# [value restrictions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx). In that case, you need to add type annotations:

```
let a<'a> : ('a -> 'a) = f >> g
```

Comment: There's a good general explaination of compose at [fsharpforfunandprofit.com](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/function-composition/)